# How to make this gridview in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I got a new task for a different kind of gridview. How do I create this type of gridview?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the HTML table using TemplateFields:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Better still use a DataList:

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/datalist.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using two nested gridviews: a gridview in the template field of another gridview.

Answer (score -3):

A Label accept to use HTML, just put the tags in there starting with `<html>`.
Maybe it's possible to do what you want.